# Is there a way to allow scripts from Cloudflare on new Google sites?

Tags: cloudflare, google-sites, google-sites-2016, cloudflare-apps

I created a site using the new Google sites (*not Classic Sites*), set up site proxying through Cloudflare, and enabled the [Email Address Obfuscation](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200171036) feature in Cloudflare. Then I added a button that performs a simple action `mailto:info@example.com` and ran into a problem: When I click on the button, I am taken to the Cloudflare "Email Protection" page with the message "You are unable to access this email address example.com".

This is for a simple reason - my browser (and it will happen with any modern browser) does not load the `email-decode.min.js` script from Cloudflare. In turn, this is due to the fact that Google Sites uses CSP >= v2 and the CSP directives are configured in such a way that they do not allow the script from Cloudflare to load.

According to Cloudflare documentation, in order to use [Scrape Shield](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200171036) you need to [update CSP headers](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/216537517-Using-Content-Security-Policy-CSP-with-Cloudflare) as follows:

```
script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'
```

This is what the new Google Sites CSP header looks like:

```
base-uri 'self';
object-src 'none';
report-uri /_/view/cspreport;
script-src 'report-sample' 'nonce-7+8CsMF6KihKnNmDwfM84w' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';
worker-src 'self';
frame-ancestors https://google-admin.corp.google.com/
```

* `nonce-<base64-value>` is updated with every request.

When loading a page that contains email I see the following error in the browser console:

```
Refused to load the script 'https://example.com/cdn-cgi/scripts/6d6ddgh8/cloudflare-static/email-decode.min.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'report-sample' 'nonce-7+8CsMF6KihKnNmDwfM84w' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.
```

I'm not sure about the reason, but the script won't load for one of two reasons:

1. The source `'self'` is not set for the `script-src` directive (I don’t think this is the case).
2. The source `'unsafe-inline'` is ignored because a cryptographic nonce is present.

It doesn't work anyway. I see two solutions, but I don't know how to implement them:

1. For the first reason (although I don't think this is the case) this could be solved if Google added the source `'self'` to the `script-src` directive, or if I had the ability to customize this header and I would do it myself.
2. For the second reason, this could be solved if Cloudflare read the `'nonce-<base64-value>'` that the Google server returns when the site is requested and adds it to its scripts.

It would be grateful if someone could share a solution to this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I figured out that the reason is the missing `'self'` source in the `script-src` directive.

I found a [forum thread](https://community.cloudflare.com/t/how-to-modify-immutable-headers-and-add-nonces-to-response-header/146165) that suggests using [Cloudflare Workers](https://workers.cloudflare.com/) to change the required data in a request / response on the fly. I also found a [ready-made example code](https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/examples/alter-headers) for a worker that allows to replace headers in the request / response.

Inspired by this idea and given that Cloudflare provides 100,000 requests per day for free, I wrote and deployed a worker code that changes the server response headers, in fact, it updates the `script-src` directive in the `content-security-policy` header, supplementing it with the sources specified in the variable `sources`.

My problem is solved, now the Cloudflare script is loading and the button is working.

* I don't promise quality code, but it works. The code could be made even more versatile, but I didn't have time for that.

Here is my worker code:

```js
addEventListener("fetch", event => {
  event.respondWith(handleRequest(event.request))
})

const sources = ["'self'"]

/**
 * The function to update a CSP directive with new sources.
 * @param {string} directive CSP directive.
 * @param {string[]} sources Sources to add to the directive.
 * @return {string} Updated CSP directive.
 */
 function updateDirective(directive, sources) {
  for (let i = 0; i < sources.length; i++) {
    if (!directive.toLowerCase().includes(sources[i])) {
      directive = directive.concat(" ", sources[i])
    }
  }
  
  return directive
}

/**
 * The function to update the Content-Security-Policy header.
 * @param {string} header The Content-Security-Policy header.
 * @param {string} directive The Content-Security-Policy directive whose sources need to be updated.
 * @param {string} sources Sources to add to the directive.
 * @return {string} Updated Content-Security-Policy header.
 */
function updateHeader(header, directive, sources) {
  let sourceHeader = header.split(';')
  let updatedHeader = []
  
  for (let i = 0; i < sourceHeader.length; i++) {
    if (sourceHeader[i].includes(directive)) {
      updatedHeader.push(updateDirective(sourceHeader[i], sources))
    } else {
      updatedHeader.push(sourceHeader[i])
    }
  }
  
  return updatedHeader.join(";")
}

async function handleRequest(request) {
  let response = await fetch(request)

  response = new Response(response.body, response)
  response.headers.set('content-security-policy',
   updateHeader(response.headers.get('content-security-policy'), "script-src", sources))

  return response
}
```

Comment: Just used this for my Google Site. Works great.